# how to access another view and it's feature on separate screen through angular portal?

Tags: angular, templates, containers, portal

I Have an angular project with lot's of component.

I am looping one component with array like this :

```
<body-chart *ngFor="..."></body-chart>
```

## **in body-chart component :**

```
<div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <button (click)="openModal">Full screen</button>
</div>
<modal>
   I want to show same canvas here that is written in above code..
   When user click on full screen , it will open this modal from same component.
</modal>
```

How can I show this component's view in modal as well as in other screen by using it's tag ()

Anyone have any idea about it ? then please mention here.

### Note :

canvas tag is managed by library, So library automatically add some divs and canvas into same container in which I put canvas tag and render dynamic UI in dom. and it is also interactive.

I tried to use it with ng-template and ng-container like this but in ng-container, my canvas can't interact with mouse and all that stuff

### What I have tried :

```
<ng-template #container>
<div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <button (click)="openModal">Full screen</button>
</div>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="container"></ng-container>
<modal>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="container"></ng-container>
</modal>
```

It will render my template both the places. in component and in  modal.

but when Template is rendered in modal, dynamically added element by library can't added in modal (non interactive canvas)

I thought that, maybe, angular will compile html tempalte at a single time instead of when modal is open. that's why dynamically added element are not rendered in the modal.

### Another Concept I found is angular portal :

I tried to use angular portal with templatePortal and component portal but failed Due to some wierd error like : **can not append of undefined from portal.js**

IS there any proper way to do this kind of scenario.
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

To display single content in multiple places you can take advantage of `ng-container` and `ng-template`

```
<ng-template #portal>
  <div>content...</div>
</ng-template>

<div class="place1">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!condition" [ngTemplateOutlet]="portal"></ng-container>
</div>

<div class="place2">
  <ng-container *ngIf="condition" [ngTemplateOutlet]="portal"></ng-container>
</div>
```

If I get you right, template doesn't show up inside `<model>` component because you are using content projection.

`<ng-content select="...">` only looks at first level of deep.

To solve this you can use `ngProjectAs`

```
<modal>
    <ng-container ngProjectAs="container" *ngTemplateOutlet="container"></ng-container>
</modal>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried your solution and know that, ngProjectAs is not work with this scenario.